# Convert absolute positions to image map coordinates

Tags: css

I have an image on which an overlay is placed holding absolute elements. I would like to convert them to image map coordinates. Is this even possible ?

The data I have :

- The size of the image
- For each point : top, left, height & width in px

I can't figure out the maths behind this...

**Edit : some code to illustrate my question ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2ct7bab/1/))**

```
expecting <area shape="circle" coord="x,x,x,x"/> 
from 
<div class="element" style="top:2px; left:2px; width: 5px; height: 5px;"></div>
Where "x,x,x,x" are calculated from the absolute positions of .element
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `<area>` is a pain in the @rse. Try a generator: http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/ . Just found this one, it might be exactly what you need: http://www.mobilefish.com/services/record_mouse_coordinates/record_mouse_coordinates.php

Comment: Actually @zer00ne I need to do this on a batch of images, not just a few. It has to be done automagically. If the conversion is possible of course, I'm not even sure about this ...

Comment: @GungaDin that's a tall order, I'll bookmark this post just in case I run into something, good luck, sir.